# Unable to Create or Write to a file as standard user

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, uac

My application creates a log file when it connects or disconnects a server. This works well win win XP.

There are no issues while I run it as admin in Vista and Win 7. But if I run this as a standard user in Vista or Win7 then it fails to create the log file, and I know this is for UAC.

But how can I bypass this situation so that my app will run as admin . DO I need to add any registry entry while installing my application so that it will always run as administrator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you really want to, you can [add a manifest](http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx) that causes your application to require UAC elevation when it is launched, but more often than not that's not what you should do.

More likely, you're writing to a path you shouldn't be. User mode applications should only write to the current users folders or the `C:\Users\Public` folder, and things like logs should go in `C:\Users\Current User Name\Application Data\Your Program Name\`. To get the ApplicationData path use `Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData)`. Or if you want to have the file shared by all users, use `Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData`.

Comment: But I don't want the log and confguration to be different (mostly the log file ) for different windows users

Comment: Ah, in that case, you need System.Environment.SpecialFolder.CommonApplicationData, which is a location that should be writeable by all standard users. Keep in mind that since multiple users could theoretically be running your app simultaneously (since Win7 has user switching) you'll need to allow multiple writers (see: FileShare Enumeration) and handle the potential for concurrent writes, or you'll need to open and close the file for each write (could have perf implications).

Comment: you really really want your app to run as standard user and Paul has given you some excellent advice

Comment: But I want to create/write files in install path (C:\program files\myapp\\), How I can do this? my app is in C#.

Comment: @Sharique, if you do this, you are being evil (you are not following the best practices). But if you really want to, follow the "add a manifest" link (http://community.bartdesmet.net/blogs/bart/archive/2006/10/28/Windows-Vista-_2D00_-Demand-UAC-elevation-for-an-application-by-adding-a-manifest-using-mt.exe.aspx) in my answer, it will tell you how to cause your program to require Administrative rights on Vista and Win7. Once you're running as Administrator you can write/create files anywhere (including C:\Program Files\...)