# How to Disable UAC for my application

Tags: c++, windows-7, windows-vista, uac

Well , when ever I am trying to run my application as administrator I am getting the following 
error, and whether to allow or not.

If I am running the app directly and not as an administrator then this seems to work. Is there Some thing I need to do to get rid of the UAC , no I dont want user to manually change the UAC settings.

Do I need to tweak registry settings only for my programe or any certificate I need to sign with.

[image]

Comment: @Subhen is this related to your earlier question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487517/unable-to-create-or-write-to-a-file-as-standard-user

Comment: @David Heffernan, The  previous question was about "How to create a file while  I am not running it as administrator" . Here I want to know how to avoid the UAC while I run my application as administrator. More over that [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4487517/unable-to-create-or-write-to-a-file-as-standard-user/4487632#4487632 "answer") seem to be for C#

Comment: @Subhen If the user runs with UAC then the system will show the elevation dialog if your app is marked in its manifest as requiring admin rights. A better solution for you would be to avoid the need to run as admin. That is what you are meant to do and what all the documentation about UAC advises you to do. What is it about your app that requires admin rights?

Comment: @David Heffernan, Some times I need to write to registry as I am keeping some info there, or also if I want to add and delete an entry to msconfig(for auto start) through registry key , this needs the admin previlage

Comment: @Subhen The officially recommended way to do this is only to request elevation when the user is about to do something that requires admin rights. Changes to auto start are normally made during software installation which typically has admin rights. But if you want admin rights, and the user enabled UAC, then you can't avoid the dialog. There are loads of articles on the subject dating back to the Vista time frame.

Comment: @David, do changes to user-local auto start trigger UAC? Skype seems to do it with no UAC dialog. The same goes about user-local registry changes, I believe.

Comment: @Sergey Tachenov Changes to restricted resources don't trigger UAC. You have to trigger the UAC elevation dialog yourself, e.g. by manifesting you app. I think your question is whether or not changes to user-local resources require admin rights and of course the answer is that they do not.

Comment: If you digitally sign your program (may also require a cross-signature, I don't remember) then the prompt won't say "unidentified program" anymore, but there will still be a prompt.  You can get rid of the prompt by separating your code out into a service that runs in an elevated context (e.g. LocalService), but that requires a good deal of effort.  Otherwise, you are stuck with a prompt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In general, you can't disable UAC. The goal of UAC is to provide a defense in depth against malware. It would be counterproductive if an Tojan could just disable UAC.

What you *can* do is accept that UAC exists, and roll with it. You shouldn't usually run as Administrator, so it's perfectly fine to get a UAC dialog when you do. For instance, Auto Start can be handled as a per-user setting, which means you don't need to be an admin to change that.

Comment: +1 for *roll with it* which is a succinct expression for the situation

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround on your machine, you can create a scheduled task that launches your application and tick the "run with highest privileges" in the general settings. Then you create a link to the sheduled task with `schtasks /run /tn "TASKNAMEINQUOTES"` as the link text. This will call the task that will run the application with elvated privileges without the UAC prompt.
More on this here: http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/create-administrator-mode-shortcuts-without-uac-prompts-in-windows-vista/

Answer (score 1):

In

```
Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

there is such item as `ConsentPromptBehaviorAdmin`. Change it.

Answer (score 0):

Configure an application to always run elevated:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc709691(WS.10).aspx#BKMK_S2

Answer (score 0):

I had a program (Notepad2)suddenly require admin rights on a win-7 system.  Seems that this can be changed easily.

Right-click the applicaiton, select properties, go to the compatibility tab, at the bottom is

> Privilege level: Run this program as an administrator.

Unclick it and OK your way out.  Worked for me.

Answer (score -1):

Your process needs to elevate its privileges. There are couple of articles about this in CodeProject but have a look at [this](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/vista-security/UACSelfElevation.aspx) one first.

Comment: His process hasn't even **started** yet!

Comment: @Billy: I agree. My answer is not of much help in this case.